# Solving $ \frac{3x+3}{\sqrt{x}}=4+\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{x^{2}-x+1}} $

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solve in $\mathbb{R}$:

$$ \frac{3x+3}{\sqrt{x}}=4+\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{x^{2}-x+1}} $$

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: $${}{}{}{}1{}{}{}{}$$

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Note that $\frac{3x+3}{\sqrt{x}}\ge 6$, with equality only at $x=1$. This comes down to the inequality $(\sqrt{x}-1)^2 \ge 0$.

Or else we can simply quote the fact that if $t$ is positive then $t+\frac{1}{t}\ge 2$.

Now look at the right-hand side. It is not hard to show, using calculus or, more easily, without using calculus, that for positive $x$ 
$$4+\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{x^2-x+1}}\le 6,$$
 with equality only at $x=1$.  This comes down to showing that 
$\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{x^2-x+1}}\le 2$, or equivalently $(x+1)^2 \le 4(x^2-x+1)$, that is, $3(x^2-2x+1) \ge 0$.

So the **only** real solution is $x=1$.

**Remark:** Or else we could start squaring and rearranging and perhaps squaring again.  Not an appealing prospect! It would likely turn something that has a reasonably nice shape into a mess.